# speed of igraph python when sorting by betweenness

Tags: python, performance, igraph

I am performing the following computation many, many times in a given graph. I take a connected component and then sort the authors by betweenness.

ordered_authors = sorted(Author_graph.vs.select(component),key = lambda x:x.betweenness(), reverse = True)

My basic question is: "Does igraph compute the betweenness for the vertices x each time I do this computation?  Or, suppose that I computed the entire betweenness list for the whole graph already.  Then does igraph reference that list in order to do these local computations?

Depending on the answer then this local computation will be a bottle neck (or not) in a larger program I'm running.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this will compute the betweenness each time you do this computation. A better way is to calculate the betweenness for all vertices in advance:

```
scores = Author_graph.betweenness()
ordered_authors = sorted(Author_graph.vs.select(component), key = lambda x: scores[x.index], reverse=True)
```